# How do I duplicate every letter in a string with JS

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm trying to double my string xyz to xxyyzz in JS but can't get it to return correctly. What am I doing wrong?

```
<script>
string=["xyz"];
for (var i=0;i<string.length;i++)
{
document.write(string[i]*2);
}
</script>
```

Comment: _What am I doing wrong?_ you are using multiplication

Comment: I guess what I should of asked was... How do I do this correctly

Comment: This is JS, not Python. ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
var string = "xyz".split('').map(function(s){return s+s}).join('');
```

I like doing it using array maps instead of for loops. It seems cleaner to me.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way would be to add the strings together (concatenation) instead of using a multiply by 2 which won't work. See below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var string = ['xyz'];

for (var i = 0, len = string.length; i < len; i++) {
    document.write(string[i] + string[i]);
}

</script>
```

Comment: That returns xyzxyz not xxyyzz

Comment: Actually the string is declared wrong anyway. But the principle of adding the two strings together will work if you corrected the string initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

A few problems:

- You've declared `string` inside an array, giving `string.length` a value of 1 as that's the number of elements
- You can't multiply strings, unfortunately. You need to concatenate them

Here's how I'd do it:

```
var string = "xyz";
var newString = "";
for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++)
    newString += string[i] + string[i];
document.write(newString);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You didn't declared a string, you declared an array of string with 1-length.
2. Your are multiplying position of array (`string[i]*2`), trying concatenating (`string[i] + string[i]`).

This should work:

```
var string = 'xyz';

for (var i = 0, len = string.length; i < len; i++) {
    document.write(string[i] + string[i]);
}
```